# pgrep -f myprogram.py returns nothing if process not running

Tags: python, ubuntu, grep, restart, autostart

Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3

I'm trying to restart my python script in case it stops. I'm using the second response from this article: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107939/how-to-restart-the-python-script-automatically-if-it-is-killed-or-dies

I've created a cron job and it starts my python script if I put something bogus in that I know will fail. However, my python script will not run when using pgrep to check when it's running.

The cron job is:

```
pgrep -f myprogram.py || nohup python /home/User/myprogram.py &  > myprogram.out
```

If I start my python script normally through command line, pgrep correctly returns the PID. When it's not running, pgrep returns nothing.

I believe my cron job is setup correctly, but pgrep isn't returning a "1 or 0" response to start the script if it's not running.

How do I get pgrep to return a value if my script is ***not*** running that the cron job will recognize and start my python script?

Comment: Can't reproduce. This needs debugging details.

Comment: myprogram.out is empty as well. Probably because the job isn't firing. What debugging would be helpful?

Comment: Anything that'll help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure... pgrep returns nothing for a process that isn't running. There isn't debugging. I need a response that will fire a cron job if a process isn't running.

Comment: The `0` or `1` used by `||` to determine what to do next isn't what it *writes to stdout*, it's the *exit status*. There's **always** an exit status; a program can't exit without one. (Okay, sometimes the exit bytes reflect a signal-based termination instead of a clean exit, but still, they exist; and those signal-based-termination cases are always nonzero, so are treated by `||` as a failure).

Comment: Run `pgrep -f myprogram.py; echo $?`, and you'll see that `$?` is _always_ populated. Thus, `if pgrep -f myprogram.py; then do_the_success_thing; else do_the_failure_thing; fi`, or `pgrep -f myprogram.py || do_the_failure_thing` both always have a result for the shell to branch on, in deciding whether `pgrep` was successful.

Comment: You seem to be using a double pipe. A single pipe means using the result of the previous command, while the double pipe means using the exit status (which is completely useless information). Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: So either 1) Go with Charle's suggestion and build an if statement, or 2) use a single pipe. The if statement was tough for me because I'm combining it with "run this every minute to check", but that could be my lack of understanding. With the single pipe will foo | bar run only if there's a 0? I changed it to a single pipe and it's starting a new process every minute (ie the condition is always true).

Comment: Sorry? `||` _does_ operate on `$?`, just as `if` does. I just was mentioning `if` as an equivalent to provide something to compare against.

Comment: ...all that said, using cron+nohup is a really lousy way to run a daemon -- it doesn't give you capabilities (like good logging, centralized status querying, ability to assert a desired status, etc) that every reasonable service management tool built in the last two decades has included out-of-the-box. Don't do that in the first place -- if your operating system ships systemd, make it a systemd service; if you're on MacOS, make it a launchd service; etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Great feedback. I really appreciate the better way of doing things. Thanks! I'll look at using systemd as services instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved very easily:

```
pgrep -f myprogram.py ... | wc -l
```

When your program is running, there is one result, so `wc -l` gives 1.
When your program is not running, there's no result, so `wc -l` gives 0.

Comment: This is true, but it imagines that the OP _had a real problem in the first place_. `foo || bar` doesn't use what `foo` writes to stdout to decide whether to run `bar`; instead, it uses `foo`'s exit status -- and `foo` **always** has an exit status. Thus, while it answers the OP's literal question, I'm not confident that it addresses the problem that led them to ask that question.

Comment: You're rigiht, I added a comment to the question.

Comment: Charles is correct. pgrep -f myprogram.py | wc -l does return a 0. I still need to couple this to some sort of if statement to run 'bar' in the foo || bar case.

Comment: pgrep will exit with a non-zero status if no process is found. what's the point of wc -l here?